# Uninstalling Teamviewer Fully

Tags: mac, macos, pkg

I have been trying to remove teamviewer fully becuase of some leftover services trying to run the app (which've already been deleted a long time ago). I do run a `find` command to see what is left from teamviewer. See below;

```
> sudo find / -name *teamviewer*
Password:

/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.Helper.plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service.plist
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.teamviewer.Helper
/private/var/db/BootCaches/FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA000000F8/app.com.teamviewer.TeamViewer.playlist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer10.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer10.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer10Agent.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer10Agent.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer10AuthPlugin.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer10AuthPlugin.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer10Font.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer10Font.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer10Restarter.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer10Restarter.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer11.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer11.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer11Agent.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer11Agent.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer11AuthPlugin.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer11AuthPlugin.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer11Font.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer11Font.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer11PriviledgedHelper.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer11PriviledgedHelper.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer11Restarter.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer11Restarter.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12Agent.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12Agent.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12AuthPlugin.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12AuthPlugin.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12Font.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12Font.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12PriviledgedHelper.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12PriviledgedHelper.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12Restarter.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer12Restarter.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer9.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer9.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer9Agent.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer9Agent.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer9Font.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.teamviewer.teamviewer9Font.plist
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.teamviewer.teamviewer.sfl
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/https_community.teamviewer.com_0.localstorage
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/https_community.teamviewer.com_0.localstorage-journal
```

so the question is is it safe to remove all those files ( I believe so, but still need some experts' help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of the services, removing

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.Helper.plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service.plist
```

is enough.

Otherwise just remove them all.

Comment: Deleted, restarted and seems the os is ok. So no harm effect.